# Django relation to two colums from another table

Tags: django

I would like to have a relation with the ToDoLists using the foreign key and have the date from the ToDoLists in my ToDoItems.
Explaining it more specifically: I want a realtion of One to Many from my ToDoLists table to te ToDoItems table so I need the foreign key to be the id of the ToDoLists but I need the date from the ToDoLists on the ToDoItems table
I have:

```
class ToDoLists(models.Model):
    todo_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=False)

class ToDoItems(models.Model):
    item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    to_do_list = models.ForeignKey(ToDoLists,related_name='to_do_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.ForeignKey(ToDoLists, to_field='date', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I would like to have a relation with the ToDoLists using the foreign key and have the date from the ToDoLists in my ToDoItems, but I get this error:

```
ERRORS:
api.ToDoItems.date: (fields.E311) 'ToDoLists.date' must set unique=True because it is referenced by a foreign key.
```

As a date I don't want it to be unique as I can have multiple To do lists with the same date

Comment: Well the `todo_id` is *unique* (since it is a primary key), hence making an extra `ForeignKey` does not make much sense I think.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought as well but I couldn't find anything on the documentation on how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only reference the `ToDoLists` model, so:

```
class ToDoLists(models.Model):
    todo_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=False)

class ToDoItems(models.Model):
    item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    to_do_list = models.ForeignKey(
        ToDoLists,
        related_name='to_do_items',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

A `ForeignKey` is a *lazy* loading getter of the related object. So you can obtain the `date` of the related `to_do_list` object of a `ToDoItems` object with:

```
mytodos_item.to_do_list.date
```

If you need this often you can make a property that automatically fetches it, or you can annotate the queryset to obtain the data in the `ToDoItems` model objects:

```
class ToDoItems(models.Model):
    item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    to_do_list = models.ForeignKey(
        ToDoLists,
        related_name='to_do_items',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    @property
    def date(self):
        return self.to_do_list.date
```

or with an [*annotation* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) in a [*manager* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/):

```
from django.db.models import F

class ToDoItemsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            date=F('to_do_list__date')
        )

class ToDoItems(models.Model):
    item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    to_do_list = models.ForeignKey(
        ToDoLists,
        related_name='to_do_items',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    objects = ToDoItemsManager()
```

It is better *not* to store the `Date` of an item you reference, since if you later update the `date` of the `ToDoLists` object, it will be hard to keep the columns in sync.

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `TodoItem` instead of <s>`ToDoItems`</s>.

Comment: also I changed the models name, thanks fo the heads up